# How does $m_2g = \frac{3gm_2}{4} + \frac{9gm}{2}$ lead to $m_2 = \frac{9/2m } {1 - 3/4} = 18m$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$m_2g = \frac{3gm_2}{4} + \frac{9gm}{2}$$

Then, my teacher wrote that

$$m_2 = \frac{9/2m } {1 - 3/4} = 18m$$

I want to know how did my teacher derive this expression . I am getting it at all.

Comment: Take the first equation and solve for $m_2$; what do _you_ get???

Comment: Please use the [Meta Read](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and enhance your question.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich m2g = (3gm2 + 18gm)/4

Comment: No, **solve for $m_2$**! That means you come up with an equation $m_2=\dots$, with no "$m_2$" on the right-hand side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$m_{2}g=\frac{3gm_{2}}{4}+\frac{9gm}{2}$$

Subtract $\frac{3gm_{2}}{4}$ from both sides of equation

$$m_{2}g-\frac{3gm_{2}}{4}=\frac{9gm}{2}$$

$$\implies m_{2}g\left(1-\frac{3}{4}\right)=\frac{9gm}{2}$$

$$\implies m_{2}g\left(\frac{4-3}{4}\right)=\frac{9gm}{2}$$

$$\implies \frac{m_{2}g}{4}=\frac{9gm}{2}$$

Multiply by $4$ on both sides of equation

$$m_{2}g=\frac{9gm}{2}×4$$

$$\implies m_{2}g=18gm$$